# Remove lines from a file that do not contain a string from list

Tags: shell, sed

Given a file containing a list of strings like:

**File1.txt**

```
ABC
DEF
HIJ
```

And a file with contents like this:

**File2.txt**

```
123 line 
ABC line
HIJ line
456 line
786 line
```

How can remove lines from the second file that do not begin with strings in first file? Also, if possible I'd like to edit the file in place rather than create a new file.

So the resulting file would contain:

```
ABC line
HIJ line
```

I was thinking of using sed to remove the lines like this.

```
sed -n -e '/^ABC\|^DEF\|^HIJ/p' File2.txt
```

However, File1.txt contains thousands of strings to check against. It would be better to use the separate file rather than list them all in this sed command.

Comment: This is tricky, in that the pattern needs to match at the beginning of line. You could create a temporary file out of File1.txt, which has a caret (`^`) at the start of each line, and then use `grep`. However this means that an entry in File1.txt which i.e. says `AB.`, would also match `ABx` and `ABy` for instance. For a _literal_ match at the start of line, it is perhaps easiest to write a small program in, say, Ruby or Perl or awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/^&/p#' file1 | sed -nf - -i file2
```

Turn file1 into a sed script and apply it to file2.

The first sed invocation creates for each line a match string which if successful prints the line.

The second sed invocation takes the output of the first and treats it as a sed script. This invocation also sets the `-n` option which ensures only the lines matched are printed and nothing else and the `-i` option which edits the file in place.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk` :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a)' File1.txt File2.txt
```

- `NR==FNR` while you are in the first file
- `a[$0]` register the line in an array `a`
- `next` go to next record
- `($1 in a)` if `$1` your first field is registered in `a`

In `awk` if you have a condition that is true, by default it will print the line, so `($1 in a)` can be read as `($1 in a){print $0}`

Using this method will make sure that you have the literal input given in your first file. For example if you have `AB.` this will only match with `AB.` and wont be considered as a regex, so wont match `ABy`.

This use an associative array, so it will store every value you have in your first file. If this file is too large you may encounter memory problem.

This will edit neither of your files, so you will need to redirect the output to a new file using this method.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contained regular expression patterns, like this:

```
^ABC
^DEF
^HIJ
```

Then it would be simple: `grep -f file1.txt file2.txt`